# Finding an element with multiple &nbsp; (Selenium webdriver Python 3)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am using Selenium (Chrome) Webdriver (**Python 3**) to find a button on a page called "Inbox" (to then click it) but I am repeatedly getting a "NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element."

This is most likely due to a number of non-breaking spaces (&nbsp) in the html (see below):

```
         <tr>
            <td class="MENUCHOICE">
               "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                       " == $0
               <a href="main.do?action=inbox">Inbox</a>
            </td>
```

I have tried a couple ways to work around the non-breaking spaces but have yet to find a solution:

1) `driver.find_element_by_link_text('     Inbox')` (adding five spaces before the link text)

2) `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[.='\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0Inbox']")`

Any suggestions for how to find the element using Python code would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**: I should mention that there is no iframe in the full HTML code and I already have a time.sleep(40) in my code to allow for enough time for the link to become clickable. I am only focused on the non-breaking spaces because I have already tried finding the element without including them; here are some examples of my attempts (without considering &nbsp):

```
find_element_by_xpath('//td[@class=’MENUCHOICE’]//a[@href="main.do?action=inbox"]')
find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[6]/td/a')
find_element_by_link_text('Inbox')
find_element_by_partial_link_text('Inb')
find_element_by_css_selector('body > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(6) > td > a')
find_element_by_css_selector("td.MENUCHOICE a[href='main.do?action=inbox']")
```

Comment: What about using the class name instead to find your element?

Answer (score 2):

Those non-breaking space characters are not part of *link text*, so you don't need to include them into anchor selectors... Try

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Inbox')  #  or driver.find_element_by_link_text('INBOX')
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[.="Inbox"]')
```

You also might need to wait for link to become clickable:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[.="Inbox"]')))
```

Comment: I am only focused on non-breaking space characters because I have already tried to find the element without including them (the way you had mentioned). There is a time.sleep(40) in my full code to allow for enough time for the link to become clickable.

Comment: @Neuro_Prog , can you share page URL if it's not private?

Comment: unfortunately the page is part of a VPN. However, I did provide the full HTML code of the page along with my own code in a previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52618687/7348723

Comment: @Neuro_Prog , considering provided HTML `driver.find_element_by_link_text('Inbox')` should work well. I don't know how did you use that `time.sleep(40)`, so it hard to tell what's wrong. Try that line with `WebDriverWait` from my answer and let me know the result

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. Unfortunately I get the TimeoutException when running the implementation. I ran 'WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Inbox')))'. This has happened to me before when trying explicit waits on this page. It's hard for me too, to tell what's wrong here as I have used selenium successfully on a number of other websites/pages with my current setup

Comment: Is it at all possible that Selenium does not work with certain pages? In my case, pages that are protected by VPNs?

Comment: @Neuro_Prog , do you use headless or visible browser? If you use visible do you actually see the page opened in browser? I don't think there might be some problem with handling page that is actually opened in browser...

Comment: I use a visible Chrome browser. I am only able to get to the Login page with the help of Selenium. The process I view on the browser when running the script is: 1) Selenium takes you to URL of the main page (visibly opened in browser), and clicks and opens the link to the Login page; 2) Once I get to the Login page, I manually type in my credentials (Selenium was giving NoSuchElementException here too); 3) I am now logged in and at the page with the Inbox button, but cannot use Selenium to click the button because of the NoSuchElementException issue

Comment: @Neuro_Prog , logging manually is also not good... These issues might be related with each other... But for now I cannot tell what's wrong - I see no reasons for exceptions

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help! Will troubleshoot the Login page first and see if that has any effect on the next page.